# Tuning Ubuntu for Java

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I'm developing a system in java that should be running 24/7 on a linux box. It is a soap consuming application and should be making about 15 calls per second. I'm aware of the premature optimization thing, but as this application is handling some considerable amounts of money I'm looking to know if there is something in Ubuntu to set up for maximum robusteness, or maybe choosing other distro or read about something, because I'm not experienced in this kind of application.

Comment: I think you will find this question is far too general for a QnA site that focus on things with definite answers. "Maximum robustness" doesn't really mean anything, isn't that what most operating systems all strive to be? Also, please take more care when asking questions to properly capitalize and punctuate, otherwise people won't want to take the time to study your question.

Comment: thanks for your comment, and sorry for having an general question

Comment: Please do *not* roll back my edits! I fixed your punctuation and capitalization so the message was readable. I also removed the signature and thanks like to comply with the site rules. If I made mistakes or you can further improve it, do so, but don't revert the whole edit.

Answer (score 1):

Distro is unlikely to make much difference in this regard. Generally speaking, 15 socket connections per second is peanuts on modern hardware. It is very likely that your code is going to be the problem, not the underlying OS. In particular, you may come to regret the overhead associated with SOAP calls. I have observed SOAP operations spending 80% or more of the CPU usage for XML-related overhead.

Some development-related answers:

- What may (unfortunately) matter is
  which JVM you are using. In
  particular, there are large
  behavioural differences between the
  various 1.6 SUN JVM versions as
  regards to memory allocation.
- One of the main problems with high
  performance Java is that the
  parameters you want to tweak are
  often hidden by abstractions. Be
  prepared to create local forks of
  third-party software. Stick to open
  source software or commercial
  suppliers where you have good support
  directly from the developers.
- All these things means that you will
  need to construct benchmark
  unit/integration tests. Write a
  client to your server that does 15
  parallel calls and see how long it
  takes to get a response. Write unit
  tests that fail if the total
  execution time of 1000 calls thru
  critical code paths take more than an
  established number of milliseconds.

If "some considerable amounts of money" translates to expensive downtime, I think that you probably want to focus on uptime rather than performance. Can your application be redundant and/or clustered? How quickly can you restore from backup?